# How to pass InkCanvas SelectedStrokes to viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inkcanvas

In a standard MVVM pattern, how is the viewmodel made aware of selected strokes from an InkCanvas?

In code-behind with knowledge of the InkCanvas, deleting selected strokes is very easy:

```
 private void btnDeleteSelectedStrokes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StrokeCollection selectedStrokes = theInkCanvas.GetSelectedStrokes();
            theInkCanvas.Strokes.Remove(selectedStrokes);

        }
```

But can this be done in a MVVM?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of a better solution, this works for me:

```
XAML
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:Notepad.Helpers" 

<InkCanvas ... h:InkCanvasExtension.IsSelectionEnabled="True"
               h:InkCanvasExtension.TheSelectedStrokes="{Binding SelectedStrokes, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Attached Properties:

```
namespace Notepad.Helpers
{
    public static class InkCanvasExtension 
    {
        /*The provider class for an attached property (even if it is not registered as a dependency property) must provide static get and set accessors 
        * that follow the naming convention Set[AttachedPropertyName] and Get[AttachedPropertyName]. These accessors are required so that the acting XAML 
        * reader can recognize the property as an attribute in XAML and resolve the appropriate types.*/

        #region [IsSelectionEnabled]
        public static bool GetIsSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectionEnabled);
        }

        public static void SetIsSelectionEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsSelectionEnabled, value);
        }

        // In XAML, IsSelectionEnabled = "true" will call OnIsSelectionEnabled().
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectionEnabled =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelectionEnabled",
            typeof(bool), typeof(InkCanvasExtension),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectionEnabled));


        private static void OnIsSelectionEnabled(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InkCanvas ic = sender as InkCanvas;
            if (ic != null)
            {
                // get the value of IsSelectionEnabled (which is either true or false).
                bool isEnabled = (bool)e.NewValue;
                if (isEnabled)
                {
                    ic.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    ic.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Assigning TheSelectedStrokes directly like: 
            //      TheSelectedStrokes = selectedStrokes
            // will not work and will break the binding. Must use:
            //      SetTheSelectedStrokes(ic, selectedStrokes);

            InkCanvas ic = sender as InkCanvas;
            StrokeCollection selectedStrokes = ic.GetSelectedStrokes();
            SetTheSelectedStrokes(ic, selectedStrokes);
        }


        #endregion

        #region [TheSelectedStrokes]
        public static StrokeCollection GetTheSelectedStrokes(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (StrokeCollection)obj.GetValue(TheSelectedStrokes);
        }

        public static void SetTheSelectedStrokes(DependencyObject obj, StrokeCollection value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TheSelectedStrokes, value);
        }

        // by default binding works one way, i.e. loading changes from the view model, but not updating it back.
        // so must add FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault to send update to the viewmodel.
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TheSelectedStrokes =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TheSelectedStrokes",
                typeof(StrokeCollection), typeof(InkCanvasExtension),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
        #endregion

    }

}
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a behavior for implementing the same.

```
public class InkCanvasDeleteBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public InkCanvas Canvas
    {
        get { return (InkCanvas)GetValue(CanvasProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CanvasProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Canvas", 
            typeof(InkCanvas), 
            typeof(InkCanvasDeleteBehavior), 
            new PropertyMetadata(null));



    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        var btnDelete = this.AssociatedObject as Button;
        if(btnDelete!=null)
        {
            btnDelete.Click += BtnDelete_Click;
        }
    }

    private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Canvas!=null)
        {
            var stokeCollection = this.Canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
            foreach (var stroke in stokeCollection)
            {
                stroke.Selected = true;
            }
            this.Canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.DeleteSelected();
        }
    }
}
```

For XAML, you can use the behavior in this way.

```
<Page
x:Class="Mock.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Mock"
xmlns:behavior="using:Mock.Behaviors"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="_canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:InkCanvasDeleteBehavior Canvas="{Binding ElementName=_canvas}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

PS: I am using UWP. In WPF, some code might be a little different but underlying logic is same.

There is another way to do this, by passing the object though a command parameter to the command and then using the command from the button to delete the item. That would also work. If you need a sample, let me know.

In addition to this, you can also use behaviors to pass the value to the view models as well. You can keep a property `StrokeCollection` in your view model and pass a reference to the behavior. When you draw something in the `InkCanvas`, update the `StrokeCollection` in the behavior which will get reflected in the `ViewModel`.

The only difference would be, the behavior would be attached to the `InkCanvas` instead of Button in the example.

Comment: I am working in WPF and with InkCanvas. I need to get to the office, but off hand don't think I have access to InkPresenter or stroke.Selected ?

Comment: Yup. You can use behaviors as well as attached properties. The only difference between using Behaviors and Attached properties is the reason why you use them. For example Grid.Row is something you attach on a control that becomes active if the control is enclosed in a grid, similary ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility and others are there.

We normally use behaviors if we want to add some functionality in some existing control. Hence my suggestion was to go with behaviors. But attached property will do the job fine as well.. Cheers :) :) 

Glad that you got a solution :) :)